# How to load images with multiple JSON annotation in PyTorch

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, deep-learning, pytorch

I would like to know how I can use the data loader in PyTorch for the custom file structure of mine. I have gone through PyTorch documentation, but all those are with separate folders with class.

My folder structure consists of 2 folders(called training and validation), each with 2 subfolders(called images and json_annotations). Each image in the "images" folder has multiple objects(like cars, cycles, man etc) and each is annotated and have separate JSON files. Standard coco annotation is followed. My intention is to make a neural network which can do real-time classification from videos.

[image: Sample image, there are around 2k images are there with 2k JSON annotations]

[image: corresponding JSON annotation file for the given image. Like this each image has separate JSON file]

Edit 1:
I have done the coding as suggested by Fábio Perez.

```
class lDataSet(data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, path_to_imgs, path_to_json):
        self.path_to_imgs = path_to_imgs
        self.path_to_json = path_to_json
        self.img_ids = os.listdir(path_to_imgs)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img_id = self.img_ids[idx]
        img_id = os.path.splitext(img_id)[0]
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(self.path_to_imgs, img_id + ".jpg"))
        load_json = json.load(open(os.path.join(self.path_to_json, img_id + ".json")))
        #n = len(load_json)
        #bboxes = load_json['annotation'][n]['segmentation']
        return img, load_json

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.image_ids)
```

When I try this

```
l_data = lDataSet(path_to_imgs = '/home/training/images', path_to_json = '/home/training/json_annotations')
```

I'm getting l_data with l_data[][0] - images and l_data with json. Now I'm confused. How will I use it with finetuning example availalbe in PyTorch? In that example, dataset and dataloader is done as shown below.
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/finetuning_torchvision_models_tutorial.html

```
# Create training and validation datasets
image_datasets = {x: datasets.ImageFolder(os.path.join(data_dir, x), data_transforms[x]) for x in ['train', 'val']}
# Create training and validation dataloaders
dataloaders_dict = {x: torch.utils.data.DataLoader(image_datasets[x], batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=4) for x in ['train', 'val']}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to implement your own dataset with [`data.Dataset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Dataset). You just need to implement `__len__` and `__getitem__` methods.

In your case, you can iterate through all images in the image folder (then you can store the image ids in a list in your `Dataset`). Then, you use the index passed to `__getitem__` to get the corresponding image id. With this image id, you can read the corresponding JSON file and return the target data that you need.

Something like this:

```
class YourDataLoader(data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, path_to_imgs, path_to_json):
        self.path_to_imags = path_to_imgs
        self.path_to_json = path_to_json
        self.image_ids = iterate_through_images(path_to_images)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img_id = self.image_ids[idx]
        img = load_image(os.path.join(self.path_to_images, img_id)
        bboxes = load_bboxes(os.path.join(self.path_to_json, img_id)
        return img, bboxes

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.image_ids)
```

In `iterate_through_images` you get all the ids (e.g. filenames) of images in a directory.
In `load_bboxes` you read the JSON and get the information you need.

I have a JSON loader implementation [here](https://github.com/fabioperez/skin-data-augmentation/blob/a96ee0c70c8907a05a19cee96710116659685ee1/auglib/dataset_loader.py#L9) if you want a reference.

Comment: I have gone through your code and it was a big help. I'm a beginner and I'm still confused. I have given those as Edit 1. Please help

Comment: You are trying to use a classification network to train an object detector. Please refer to some object detector tutorials https://github.com/sgrvinod/a-PyTorch-Tutorial-to-Object-Detection.